# iOS autoscaling for iphone 6 & 6+

Tags: ios, swift, scaling

My iOS app under iOS iPhone 6 & 6+ simulator has been using the native resolution and I am unsure of how to change it back to use the scaled version provided by Apple.

Comment: So your question is...?

Comment: My question is that the spritekit app doesn't scale to fit iphone 6 and iphone 6+ anymore

Comment: @Wraithseekerr So do you think you did something to make this happen? What could it be? Update the question with some more details.

Comment: updated with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had edited my launch screen file that was causing the problem.